How can I convert mediapipe 3D keypoints to eular angles of a skeleton?
I have code snippet to convert openpose 3D keypoints to eular angles of a skeleton. The keypoints detected from openpose could be seen in below image:

The code which converts these 3D keypoints to eular agnles of a skeleton is:
def pose2euler(self, pose, header):
    channel = []
    quats = {}
    eulers = {}
    stack = [header.root]
    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        joint = node.name
        joint_idx = self.keypoint2index[joint]
        
        if node.is_root:
            channel.extend(pose[joint_idx])

        index = self.keypoint2index
        order = None
        if joint == 'Hip':
            x_dir = pose[index['LeftHip']] - pose[index['RightHip']]
            y_dir = None
            z_dir = pose[index['Spine']] - pose[joint_idx]
            order = 'zyx'
        elif joint in ['RightHip', 'RightKnee']:
            child_idx = self.keypoint2index[node.children[0].name]
            x_dir = pose[index['Hip']] - pose[index['RightHip']]
            y_dir = None
            z_dir = pose[joint_idx] - pose[child_idx]
            order = 'zyx'
        elif joint in ['LeftHip', 'LeftKnee']:
            child_idx = self.keypoint2index[node.children[0].name]
            x_dir = pose[index['LeftHip']] - pose[index['Hip']]
            y_dir = None
            z_dir = pose[joint_idx] - pose[child_idx]
            order = 'zyx'
        elif joint == 'Spine':
            x_dir = pose[index['LeftHip']] - pose[index['RightHip']]
            y_dir = None
            z_dir = pose[index['Thorax']] - pose[joint_idx]
            order = 'zyx'
        elif joint == 'Thorax':
            x_dir = pose[index['LeftShoulder']] - \
                pose[index['RightShoulder']]
            y_dir = None
            z_dir = pose[joint_idx] - pose[index['Spine']]
            order = 'zyx'
        elif joint == 'Neck':
            x_dir = None
            y_dir = pose[index['Thorax']] - pose[joint_idx]
            z_dir = pose[index['HeadEndSite']] - pose[index['Thorax']]
            order = 'zxy'
        elif joint == 'LeftShoulder':
            x_dir = pose[index['LeftElbow']] - pose[joint_idx]
            y_dir = pose[index['LeftElbow']] - pose[index['LeftWrist']]
            z_dir = None
            order = 'xzy'
        elif joint == 'LeftElbow':
            x_dir = pose[index['LeftWrist']] - pose[joint_idx]
            y_dir = pose[joint_idx] - pose[index['LeftShoulder']]
            z_dir = None
            order = 'xzy'
        elif joint == 'RightShoulder':
            x_dir = pose[joint_idx] - pose[index['RightElbow']]
            y_dir = pose[index['RightElbow']] - pose[index['RightWrist']]
            z_dir = None
            order = 'xzy'
        elif joint == 'RightElbow':
            x_dir = pose[joint_idx] - pose[index['RightWrist']]
            y_dir = pose[joint_idx] - pose[index['RightShoulder']]
            z_dir = None
            order = 'xzy'
        if order:
            dcm = math3d.dcm_from_axis(x_dir, y_dir, z_dir, order)
            quats[joint] = math3d.dcm2quat(dcm)
        else:
            quats[joint] = quats[self.parent[joint]].copy()
        
        local_quat = quats[joint].copy()
        if node.parent:
            local_quat = math3d.quat_divide(
                q=quats[joint], r=quats[node.parent.name]
            )
        
        euler = math3d.quat2euler(
            q=local_quat, order=node.rotation_order
        )
        euler = np.rad2deg(euler)
        eulers[joint] = euler
        channel.extend(euler)

        for child in node.children[::-1]:
            if not child.is_end_site:
                stack.append(child)

    return channel

Now I want to achieve the eular angles for mediapipe keypoints, but I am not able to understand the above code. How and why are x_dir, y_dir, and z_dir being calculated? Can anyone please explain this to me? I am working on a project, and I have been stuck here from 4 weeks. The keypoints calculated from Mediapipe are shown in the below image:

Only working for pose keypoints not for face.
